# Python Script throwing TTY Sudo error when running SUDO Command

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests, sudo

```
def execute_cli_locally(command, timeout=CLI_EXECUTION_TIMEOUT,
                    return_output_as_string=True)

try:
    logger.info("Executing commands locally :\n%s", command)
    ssh = Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

    stdout, stderr = ssh.communicate(command)

    if ssh.returncode == 0:
        stdout = stdout.strip()
        if len(stdout) != 0:
            logger.info("Stdout :\n%s", stdout)
        return stdout

    else:
        logger.error("Local command execution failed. Error :\n%s" % stderr)
        print_response_and_exit(STATUS_FAILED,
                                "Local commands [%s] execution failed. Error :\n%s" %
                                (command, stderr))
```

I am executing SUDO command to this python script, but is throwing error "sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo".

Comment: Have you tried ssh -t user@example.com sudo command /path/to/file, i.e. use -t switch?

Comment: yes, i tried with '-t' as well, but it throwing same error

Comment: Can you paste the output for: sudo cat /etc/sudoers | grep requiretty

Comment: Defaults    requiretty
# changed in order to be able to use sudo without a tty. See requiretty above.
Defaults:consul !requiretty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run your script using

`sudo -S python {script_name} {args}`.

It worked for me in some such cases.

Answer (score 0):

1. Type this in terminal:

sudo visudo /etc/sudoers

2. find this line:

Defaults requiretty

and comment out the line using '#' i.e. #Defaults requiretty.

3. Save and close the file:

In vi/vim: type “:wq” – this means pressing : first, which activates the command mode, then typing wq and pressing Enter. This sequence will save the file and exit the editor.

In nano: press Ctrl+X, then y to confirm you want to save changes. Then press Enter without changing the default filename.

Comment: It Worked.. You are genius.. Is there any way to do this in comment line, as i should not able to change that file in production environment

Comment: Some Linux distributions have been known to have this as a default configuration. RedHat just recently removed this from Fedora and REHL. If error occurs in production environment then I suggest you post another question with details about you production environment so that question will be helpful for other people who are looking for solutions.